# Charges on a tree

Tags: electrostatics

[image: charges on a tree]

Can anyone tell me why is the tree in this photo charged with a positive charge although I thought it must be neutral.

Comment: If the tree hadn't had the positive charge the lightning wouldn't have collided it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an induced charge.  Since the cloud has a negative charge on its bottom, the tree (which is normally neutral) has extra positive charge in it that is being attracted towards the cloud.

Comment: So do you mean that the negative charges of the cloud are the reason why the positive charges on the tree are concentrated at the top of the tree, and you mean that the tree is still neutral but its positive charges are just concentrated at the top.

Comment: It is more than just the tree that must be considered here.  Positive charge from everywhere nearby the tree (such as the ground) also collects near the top of the tree.  The tree is no longer neutral, because the negative charges in the cloud are pulling positive charges toward them.

Comment: So what happens is that 1: the tree is neutral 2: the cloud comes over the tree 3: the the negative charges of the cloud make the positive charges of the tree get concentrated at the top of the tree 4: the negative charges of cloud make the positive charges leave the tree due to the attraction and the electric current happens 5: when the positive charges leaving the tree increase the current gets bigger and the Lightning happens.

Comment: Basically, yes.